# How to split data by using train_test_split in Python Numpy into train, test and validation data set? The split should not random

Tags: python, numpy, train-test-split

I want to split data category wise into train, test and validation set. For example: if we have 3 categories positive, negative and neutral in the dataset. The positive category split into train, test, and validation. And the same with the other two categories. The splitting ratio is 80% of the data is for training and 20% for testing. From 80% of the training data, split 10% for the validation data. But the most important the split data should not random.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stratify` parameter to do this:

For example:
If you were to use Iris dataset to do this.

```
from sklearn import cross_validation, datasets 

X = iris.data[:,:2]
y = iris.target

cross_validation.train_test_split(X,y,stratify=y)
```

You can read more here:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: It doesnt matter. The stratify variable takes care of this. It can have any number of classes.

Comment: Welcome. Please do mark it as answer so that others may get the benefit as well